# How to interrupt animations

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

Is there a way to either:
1. prioritize a certain string over another
 or
2. interrupt a currently running string and start a new string?

i have a following code like this. it is supposed to turn the button color from green->yellow->flashes to purple->return to green:

html:

```
<input id="i" type="button" value="I" style="width:80px;height:80px;color:#ffffff;background-color:#0CEDCF;border-color:#1BE0DD"/>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#i').animate({backgroundColor: "#F8FF2B"},900);
    setTimeout(
    function(){
      $('#i').css('color', '#5142F5');
      $('#i').css('background-color', '#F760F2');
    }, 350);
    setTimeout(
    function(){
      $('#i').animate({backgroundColor: '#0CEDCF'},302);
    }, 480);
    setTimeout(
    function(){
      $('#i').css('color', '#FFFFFF');
    }, 602);
```

basically, i want the

```
$('#i').animate({backgroundColor: "#F8FF2B"},900);
```

to stop its effect as soon as its the time for

```
setTimeout(
function(){
      $('#i').css('color', '#5142F5');
      $('#i').css('background-color', '#F760F2');
}, 350);
```

to activate. so far, the only way that i can do this is to shorten the 900 to 350, but my program sometimes requires me to stick it with 900 in order for it to work properly in other functions.

Comment: use [.stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by  using [jquery stop();](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

When time meets your criteria call stop function on *`i`*

```
$('#i').stop();
```

Answer (score 0):

To stop the animation and clear the queue, remove any more animations which will occur after curent animation, use :

```
$('#i').stop(true, true);
```

[From the docs](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) :

`.stop( [clearQueue ] [, jumpToEnd ] )`

Where `clearQueue` is a boolean indicating whether to remove queued animation as well and 
`jumpToEnd` indicates whether to complete the current animation immediately. Defaults to false.